# Java swing keylistener

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

I have simplified my code and i was able to successfully create key bindings. So now in my maze i have an element(red square) that i want to move right when pressing the right key. I have the class Test and the class Element. The element has a position defined by the attributes x and y. The function printFrame displays the maze in a JPanel with a Gridlayout. The element position is a red square. When the right key is pressed the element position is updated by the RIGHTaction class. Now how can i update the mazePanel with the element new position? Should i update the cells array with the new element position and the JPanel is updated automatically?
And what about the previous position of the element? Should i set the gray color for that position so i dont get two red squares?
If i want the code to stop when the element position is x==9 and y==7 how should i do it? Shoul i create a loop for the program to run while the element position is different from the final position? Where should i put that loop?
My new code is in the links:
Test class: http://pastebin.com/d0n7qwqa
Element class: http://pastebin.com/HBWXt6zd

Comment: *"What am i missing?"*  A comparison of 'expected' vs 'actual' results?  Note:  For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`.

Comment: You have to add your KeyListener to the frame: `frame.addKeyListener(this);`

Comment: Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for an example of using Key Bindings to move an image on a panel.

Comment: I just dont know what i should do. Where exactly should i put frame.addKeyListener(this);? I have seen a lot of examples but in all of them they use the keys to move a shape on the screen. But in my case i have a JPanel that has a GridLayout and I want to change the JPanels on that grid when i press the arrow keys.